# Extract anything after a specific character (excluding the specific character)

Tags: r, regex

How can I only get "C6:C7" from "s13$C6:C7" (anything after the \$ excluding the \$ itself)

```
str_extract("s13$C6:C7", '((\\$)=?).*')
```

this one still gives me the \$ at the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

We can use regex lookaround `(?<=`) to match the characters (`.*`) that succeeds the `$` sign

```
library(stringr)
str_extract("s13$C6:C7", '(?<=\\$).*')
[1] "C6:C7"
```

---

Or use `str_remove` to match the characters till the `$` to remove those

```
str_remove("s13$C6:C7", '.*\\$')
[1] "C6:C7"
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a capture group around the dollar sign `((\\$)=?).*` but if you want to extract it you can use the  capture group for the second part of the pattern instead of the first part.

```
str_match("s13$C6:C7", '\\$(.*)')[2]
```

Output

```
[1] "C6:C7"
```

---

Note that `.*` can also match empty strings. If there should be at least a single char after the dollar sign and you want to for example match the allowed characters with a colon in between:

```
str_match("s13$C6:C7", '\\$([A-Z0-9]+(?::[A-Z0-9]+)*)$')[2]
```

See an [R demo](https://tio.run/##K/r/PyczqSixqFKjuKQoMy@9SJMLyIjPTSxJztBQKjY0VnE2s3I2V9JRUI@JUdGIdtSNMtC1jNXWsLeygnM0tTRV1DWjjWL//wcA).

Answer (score 1):

We could also use `str_replace`:

`.*` 0 or more characters to account for the optional closing parenthesis, hyphen, and space characters

`\\$` ends with `$`

```
library(stringr)
str_replace("s13$C6:C7", '.*\\$', '')
[1] "C6:C7"
```